# Security of postgresql pg.Pool connection pool credentials

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, security

How to securely store postgresql pg.Pool connection pool credentials in a node.js implementation? After setting config object to pass to pg.Pool it is stored unencrypted in the Pool object, which means it is visible in memory at all times.

Does pg.Pool have a callback mechanism whereby it could call your function to decrypt on the fly only when it needs the credentials, or somehow secure it somewhere else other than storing it in the pool object, with the goal of keeping it out of memory for extended amounts of time in an unencrypted state?

Please advise.

Comment: But that's strictly the server-side, you are not leaking it to the client-side. So what's your concern?

Comment: My concern is that if a hacker is able to obtain a memory dump there will be a plain text password in there to access the database, along with the database name, user name, etc.   I'm asking if there is any way currently to protect against this vulnerability?  I'm also suggesting that it is possible to protect against this vulnerability, and there should be a way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does pg.Pool have a callback mechanism whereby it could call your function to decrypt on the fly only when it needs the credentials

No such thing, because the connection details are meant strictly for the server-side.

You can only decrypt the connection just before creating the `Pool` object. After that it will be kept internally by the object.

In a corporate environment, your database server should simply reside within DMZ.

Comment: Yes, that is my understanding.  I was just wondering if there was another way to secure the Pool config details from a memory dump attack, since it is vulnerable to it.   In a shared host environment it becomes more of an issue because the security and monitoring of the machine is out of your hands.

Comment: @CaptAmericode the only possible approach at present is to protect the server. Once that's breached - you are exposed. That's why a proper hosting for secure things requires the server within DMZ.

Comment: Thanks for adding that information about DMZ.  If you add this info into your answer I will accept it, as I think it makes your answer more complete.